# How to fix a H10 error on Heroku, deploying a Rails and React app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I have created a website and am trying to release it on Heroku.
Frontend - React : https://github.com/Dwake5/Mollys-pet---home-care
Backend - Rails : https://github.com/Dwake5/mollys-pet---home-care-backend

I have created a procfile (backend) as such:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

And a .env file (frontend) like this:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port`);
});
```

The backend works fine, can fetch api calls from it and can visit it.
Looking at the Heroku logs --tail, I get this error message.

```
2020-08-05T13:56:23.393124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mollyspetandhomecare.herokuapp.com request_id=28ae7ce9-ae45-4a47-87d8-16ec59b31f97 fwd="92.5.55.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-05T13:59:35.709729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mollyspetandhomecare.herokuapp.com request_id=71b4d4d4-4ffc-4354-a0dc-21f7b1e11a46 fwd="92.5.55.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-05T13:59:39.981023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mollyspetandhomecare.herokuapp.com request_id=78899659-74b1-478b-81df-3ee14f79a750 fwd="92.5.55.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-05T14:06:24.755065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mollyspetandhomecare.herokuapp.com request_id=fdf741ec-9aa4-4c71-9997-4d18036c4863 fwd="92.5.55.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-05T14:06:35.319673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mollyspetandhomecare.herokuapp.com request_id=84a4997b-1b64-4bb0-8c5a-78ca5903abfd fwd="92.5.55.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the R10 error?

Comment: I meant H10, my mistake.

Comment: I got the backend to display what what port it is on: 42757
Calling 'heroku run printenv' from the front end gives: PORT=29093

I am unsure where these come from and how to align them.

Comment: The `PORT` environment variable is set by Heroku. Are you saying both applications need the same `PORT` variable? If so, that's not going to be possible. What are you trying to accomplish using that variable? Depending on what you're trying to do, you'll almost certainly need to use a fully qualified URL to communicate between the two applications.

Comment: My thought was that once those two PORTs are the same, the applications will be able to talk to each other and then the app would work.

Comment: On Heroku my last React app framework was React.js(create react app). However this one says Node.js. Could this be an issue?